# Trying to Use awk by implementating a condition and implication

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, pipe

I have a file containing 8 columns, One of my tasks is to get the values of Column 3 and if the value of the row is not equal to 123 the 8 coloumns will be printed and hence If column 3 is equal to 123 nothing will be printed

part of the program is ->

```
testing=`echo $C3  | awk '!/123/ {print $C1, $C2, $C3, $C4, $C5, $C6, $C7, $C8,}'>>final.txt`
```

and the related error is

```
 awk: illegal field $(), name "C1"
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
```

where I found that for  Lines not containing `123` it can be scripted as
`awk '!/123/'` from [Negative matching using grep (match lines that do not contain foo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo).

I also tried

```
testing=`echo $C3  | awk '!/123/ ; END {print $C1, $C2, $C3, $C4, $C5, $C6, $C7, $C8,}'>>final.txt`
```

however it also gives an error.

Comment: not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but fields in awk are numbered $1 up and don't relate to the fields in the shell. So the value of $C3 in the shell is passed over to awk as a line and then it is broken up (space-delimited) into fields $1 $3 $4 up. Also you are trying to set variable testing while piping the output into a file?

Comment: 1) try `man awk`
2) use `$1` , `$5` to refer to value of 1st or 5th column, not `$C1` or `$C5`.
use `$3 != 123` (before `{ }` part ) to filter on third column

Comment: I have another idea however i am finding it difficult how to implement it, If i have a value in column 3 equal to 123 then delete the entire row corresponding to that entry.

so far i ve done this 
`echo $C3   | awk '$1==123 {print $1}'`

I just need help in how to implement the deleting procedure in awk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your input. What is `$C3`? What are the other `$CN` supposed to be?

Comment: $C3 refer to column 3 in a particular file

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is specifically designed to deal with columnar files. It will automatically split each input line on whitespace (or anything else you give it via its `-F` switch) and the columns will then be available to `awk` as `$1`, `$2`, ..., `$N`.

So, to print lines whose 3rd column (as defined by whitespace) is not `123`, you would do:

```
awk '$3!="123"' file
```

The default action of `awk` when something evaluates to true is to print. Therefore, the command above will print all lines of `file` whose 3rd column isn't `123`.